# ngnix alias не могу понять

Tags: nginx

У меня есть server вида

```
server {
 root /var/www/*****/html;
        charset utf-8;
        index index.php signin.html index.html;

    location / {
                alias /var/www/myclending/;
                index index.html;
        }

        location /cb{
        root /var/www/*******/html/;
        index index.php signin.html index.html;
        }


}
```

Беда в том что по пути `/var/www/myclending/` файлы статического lending страницы с css и js , а в папка `/var/www/*******/html/` php скрипт. Так вот пхп скрипт работает отлично а алиас выдаёт 404 хотя папка 100% есть. Где я напортачил ?

Использую HTTPS на http работает всё превосходно

Comment: Укажите ссылку, которая выдаёт 404, и полный путь файлу, который ожидается по этой ссылке

Comment: корень выдаёт ошибку, а файл /var/www/myclending/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему так , но если это не лучший способ укажите носом

```
location / {

                try_files $uri /lending/index.html;

                location ~ ^/(.+\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|woff))$ {
                alias /var/www/*****/html/lending/$1;
                }
        }

 location /cb {
                root /var/www/*******/html/;
                index index.php signin.html index.html;
        }
```